# MySQL GROUP BY ignore or skip other null column

Tags: mysql, null, record

I have a table:

```
(id, storage_id, product_id, quantity, property_storage_group_id)
```

[image]

And I need min quantity, but when `prouct_id` is several, I need to ignore `product_id` with `property_storage_group_id = null`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(quantity), product_id
FROM storage_quantity
WHERE storage_id = 6 
GROUP BY product_id
```

but without id 22, and with id 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subqueries. Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(s1.quantity), s1.product_id
FROM storage_quantity s1
WHERE s1.id NOT IN (SELECT s2.id
                    FROM storage_quantity s2
                    WHERE s2.product_id = s1.product_id
                      AND s2.storage_id = s1.storage_id
                      AND s2.property_storage_group_id IS NULL
                      AND (SELECT COUNT(s3.property_storage_group_id)
                         FROM storage_quantity s3
                         WHERE s3.product_id = s2.product_id
                           AND s3.storage_id = s2.storage_id
                        ) > 0
                   )
WHERE s1.storage_id = 6
GROUP BY s1.product_id
```

The second subquery utilizes the fact that the `COUNT()` function automatically ignore `NULL` values, so it only returns the count of `property_storage_group_id` that are not `NULL`. If that count is greater than zero, then the first subquery selects all records with `property_storage_group_id IS NULL` for that `product_id`. Finally the main query excludes those records returned by the second query.